# Audio problem after reboot: Headphone still works, but not builtin speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, intel, headphones

having a AIO-computer with intel sound and 18.04, I ran into a problem: Sound was working well, but after a crash reboot the internal (analog) speakers do not work anymore, while plugging in a headphone works as usual.

Yes, I've checked all tools like alsamixer, pavucontrol and the desktop mute- and volume sliders

- it's not muted
- I'v tried volume values in the range 00 - 100.
- pavucontrol's indicator is moving and shows that there is sound, it's just that the speakers don't work.
- I don't see how it could be a driver problem, since it was working correctly before the crash reboot.

(alsa-info will follow)

Comment: Meta-Question: How do I attach the alsa-info output here? It's 1369 lines with 35455 characters, but neither the question, nor the comment input allow this, and file attachments are not offered either.

Comment: It's, btw., a Realtek ALC662 rev3

Comment: Will [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) do what you need to 'attach' the alsa-info output?